# Overloading less than operater with different types

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload the less than operator in order to use vector::lower_bound to find the closest/nearest number in a vector of type ClassA to a given double.
I can get it to work if i give it 2 instances of ClassA to compare but can't with different types.

I have the following code

```
double ClassB::findNearest()
{
     std::vector<ClassA> vec;
     std::vector<ClassA>::iterator low;
     low = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(), 20.0);

     if (low == vec.end())
     {
          return -1;
     }
     return *low;
}
```

## -----------------------------------------------------

```
class ClassA
{
public:
   ClassA(void);
   virtual ~ClassA(void);

   double one;
   double two;

    inline friend bool operator< ( const ClassA &cC1, const double &cC2)
    { 
         return cC1.one < cC2 ;
    };
};
```

i get the error:
binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const double' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

... and i don't know why when i've overloaded the operator from right to left. Why do i need to go the other way?

Many Thanks

Alex

Comment: the operator you wrote takes a double on the right, not on the left. The error says 'no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const double''

Comment: Is this actually the code giving you this error message? Is it really ok with `return *low;` or did it not get that far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix is to provide a non-member function (perhaps a friend if you were to make the data fields private):

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    //as before...

    inline friend bool operator< ( const double &cC1, const ClassA &cC2)
    { 
         return cC1 < cC2.one ;
    };
};
```

This feels a bit messy.
If we'd asked `std::lower_bound` to find the lower bound of a `ClassA` we wouldn't have needed to concentrate on which way round to do this.

We could allow implicit conversion by having a constructor take a `double`

```
CLassA(double x): one(x), two(0.0) {}
```

Scott Meyers talks about this at length (e.g. Item 24 Effective C++). This can end up with temporaries when we don't want it, but does allow a symmetry with non-member operators.

Alternatively, have a comparison function for `ClassA` with its own type, and make a suitable ClassA for lower_boud, e.g. ClassA(20.0, 0.0).

Comment: Can you explain, *why* must `operator<(const double&, const classA&)` be defined? I can't find such requirement in the standard. Is the standard library allowed to impose the requirement?

Comment: No, since the code actually compiles on my machine once I change the return line at the end of `findNearest`

Answer (score 1):

`std::lower_bound` is looking for: `bool operator< (const double& cC1, const ClassA& cC2)`

You should simply define that <strike>in your `ClassA`</strike> and you'll be golden:

```
bool operator< (const double& cC1, const ClassA& cC2)
{
    return cC1 < cC2.one;
}
```

**EDIT:** [leemes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592323/leemes) is right this needs to be defined outside your `Class A` so it accessable to `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: "...define that in your `ClassA`" That's wrong. This operator can't be a member, so you either have to define it outside or use the non-member friend syntax like in the question's code snippet.

Comment: The standard states `Returns: ... such that for any iterator j
... the following corresponding conditions hold: *j < value or ...`. It doesn't give any limitations for the type `T`, but I find it odd that the operator for `value < *j` must be defined instead.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I have the feeling your code might be incomplete. Your Function

```
double ClassB::findNearest()
```

returns double but works on `std::vector<ClassA>;` When it dereferences the iterator I get an error in my GCC 4.8.3 since it fails to transform ClassA to double. If however I add a cast operator to ClassA like:

```
operator double () { 
    return one; 
}
```

The `std::lower_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(), 20.0);` works for me without any custom less operator at all, since now the compiler knows a valid way of comparing ClassA to double.